# Getting a unique count based on a criteria in a different column

Tags: excel, google-sheets

I want to be able to get a unique count of docks where the version is not 2.0(9c). This is an example of what my sheet looks like.

So in this example I would want an output of '4', I want to include the blanks.

```
| Dock | Cell | Version | 
|------|------|---------| 
| 7    | 1    | 2.0(9c) | 
| 7    | 2    | 2.0(4d) | 
| 8    | 1    |         | 
| 8    | 2    | 2.0(9c) | 
| 9    | 1    | 2.0(3e) | 
| 9    | 2    |         | 
| 10   | 1    | 5.0(2e) | 
| 10   | 2    | 2.0(9c) | 
| 11   | 1    | 2.0(9c) | 
| 11   | 2    | 2.0(9c) |
```

This is what I currently have: `=SUMPRODUCT(1/COUNTIFS("<>2.0(9c)",C2:C9,A2:A9,A2:A9))`

But that errors out with the message, "Array arguments to COUNTIFS are of different size."

Here's an example of a site that does this already: http://www.get-digital-help.com/2011/07/12/count-unique-distinct-values-that-meet-multiple-criteria-in-excel/

But when I attempted to do something like that, it kept giving me 0.

Comment: That's not how you use `countifs`...

Comment: @findwindow Is there another function I can use to get this count?

Comment: `=COUNTIFS(C2:C9,"<>2.0(9c)")` all by itself nothing else.

Comment: @ScottCraner That'll only get me the count of cells which aren't "2.0(9c)". Though the example I originally posted will yield 4 with that formula, bringing it over to the actual sheet doesn't yield the correct answer. I've updated the example to reflect that.

Comment: shouldn't the anser be 5? 4d,3e, 2e and two blanks is 5

Comment: @ForwardEd No, I'm trying to get a count of the docks where the versions are not "2.0(9c)". In this example, there are 4 docks where the version is not "2.0(9c)" or it's blank.

Comment: is it always 2 cells?

Comment: @ScottCraner Yes that's correct, there will always be two cells. Each dock will always have two cells, not more not less.

Comment: @MarcoVos Sorry no, I'm trying to get a count of the docks where the versions are not "2.0(9c)", not get the number of cells which are not 2.0(9c). In that formula it got a `SUM` of all the cells not equal to "2.0(9c)".

Comment: ok, which are the 4 docks that are not 2.0(c) or space? because I dont see how you ar coming up with 4 based on the question.

Comment: @ForwardEd you're counting the same dock twice.

Comment: So if I got this straight, in this example, only dock 11 does not count because both cells are 2.0(9c)?  or does not dock 7 not count because cell 1 has 2.0(9c)?

Comment: @ForwardEd I'm expecting the following docks to be counted: 7,8,9,10. Those four docks contain a cell in which it's version number is not "2.0(9c)".

Comment: OK samwell that is much clearer, in your initial question one could have made the assumption that dock 7 did not count cause one of the cells has 2.0(9c)

Comment: @ForwardEd Yes that's correct only dock 11 does not count. Dock 7 will be counted because cell 2's version is 2.0(4d).

Comment: @ForwardEd Okay thanks, glad that cleared it up. I'll modify the original question to make it more clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this, we needed to make up for the doubles:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(($A$2:$A$11<>$A$1:$A$10)*(COUNTIFS($A$2:$A$11,$A$2:$A$11,$C$2:$C$11,"<>2.0(9c)")>0))
```

One caveat It must be sorted on column A

[image]

For Google Sheets:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((MOD(ROW($A$2:$A$11),2)=1)*(((C1:C10<>"2.0(9c)")+(C2:C11<>"2.0(9c)"))>0))
```

This formula will also work in Excel but the first will only work there.

[image]

Comment: So if I got this straight you are counting the number of docks where either 1 or both cells do not equal 2.0(9c)

Comment: @ForwardEd we only want to count every other so I did the `($A$2:$A$11<>$A$1:$A$10)`; I guess I could have done `(MOD(row($A$2:$A$11),2)=0)` and done the same.  Then the COUNTIFS() on the how many have the same dock number and have the wrong version.  without the first it would return 2 for Dock 9 twice.  I only care if it is greater than 1.

Comment: @ScottCraner Is it suppose to be `($A$2:$A$11<>$A$1:$A$10)` or should it be `($A$2:$A$11<>$A$2:$A$11)`

Comment: It is supposed to be as I have it.  We want to offset the check by one cell.  So it grabs every other one. @samwell.  Change your formula to mine and it will work.  I did not photoshop the answer.

Comment: Sorry in the first image I posted I changed the formula to address the question I had before. Here's a screenshot with your formula: http://i.imgur.com/2VCwLEA.png

Comment: @Samwell do you normally use , or ; to separate parameters in excel formulas?  I used scott's formula and its spits out the right answer.

Comment: @samwell interesting Excel gives one answer and Google Sheets another.  It works in Excel which you tagged.  Someone else will need to come up with one that works in google sheets.  I do not use it enough to be able to figure out why the difference.  I get `5` for the answer.

Comment: @ForwardEd No I don't really use `;` to separate parameters. I am doing this in Google Spreadsheet, so I copied it over to Excel and it works fine. Hmm...

Comment: @ScottCraner Okay thanks for your help! I figured Excel and Google Spreadsheets would only use the same functions to figure this out so I tagged both.

Comment: @ScottCraner Sweet thank you Scott! I changed it from `=` to `<>` to be able to get the unique count of docks with cells that are not "2.0(9c)" versions. It looks like it's producing the correct number when I changed it. Is that right?

Comment: You are correct. I will fix later. I am away from my computer. @samwell

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to do something with cell formulas, you could do

equals

```
=if(c2="2.0(9c)",1,0)
```

does not equal

```
=if(c2="2.0(9c)",0,1)
```

In the fourth column, then just SUM the column.

Comment: I'm trying to get a count of the docks where the versions are not "2.0(9c)", not get the number of cells which are not 2.0(9c). Using `SUM` and that formula will only yield me the number of cells which are not 2.0(9c).

Comment: So just reverse the 1 and 0

Comment: That still results in only getting the count of cells in which their versions are 2.0(9c). For example dock 9 has two cells which the versions are not "2.0(9c)" or blank. Using this formula or the reverse, it'll count both cells. I'm trying to get a unique count on the number of docks which have a cell which is not "2.0(9c)".

Answer (score 0):

There's very simple formula for **google sheets:**

```
=COUNTA(UNIQUE(FILTER(A2:A,C2:C<>"2.0(9c)")))
```

It's also easy to add more conditions into `filter` function.